# Is there a version of perror that takes arguments?

Tags: c

I want to print an error string with variables.

```
printf("Hi, %s", name);
perror-something("Error no: %d", number);
```

How do I add variables to `perror`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [sprintf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) for that.
Then use the result in `perror`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the combination of strerror and the fprintf.

Consider,

```
 fprintf(stderr,"%s:Error NO:%d\n",strerror(errno),number);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not a standard version of `perror()` anyway.
Instead I would simply use `fprintf()` to `STDERR`. You could `#define` so the name is more descriptive, but either way `fprintf`(stderr, .....)` will do the job simply enough.